# Maintain different version of java method under feature flag

Tags: java-8

Considering the follow method in SomeService.class

```
List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectDetails(String s){
    someRepo.get(s);
}
```

Now let's say I want to have a feature flag that I can turn off or on, and depending of it's value it will perform a different operation. The way I found to do this is with a simple if

```
List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectDetails(String s){
    if(someFeatureFlag == false){
      someRepo.get(s);
    } else {
      newRepo.get(s);
    }
}
```

I find this code appalling and the idea of maintaining different code versions using a feature flag disturbing.
Is there a better way for this method only to follow the correct code path based on a feature flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `Map`:

```
 Map<Boolean, Function<String, List<SomeObject>>> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(false, someRepo::get);
 map.put(true,  newRepo::get)
```

And later usage:

```
 List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectDetails(String s, boolean someFlag){
     return map.get(someFlag).apply(s);
 }
```

If you think that you can later have even more cases, think of introducing an `enum`:

```
 enum Version {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD
 }


 FirsRepo fr = new FirsRepo();
 EnumMap<Version, Function<String, List<SomeObject>>> map = new EnumMap<>(Version.class);
 map.put(Version.FIRST, fr::get);
 // all others...


 List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectDetails(String s, Version version){
     map.get(version).apply(s);
 }
```

Comment: Too much attempt to bring functional programming into the solution. After all, you’re not intending to abstract the `get` operation of `Map`. So you could simply put references to the maps instead of functions into the map and use `map.get(version).get(s)`. In case of a `boolean` key, you still may use `(someFeatureFlag? newRepo: someRepo).get(s)`…

Comment: well this was watered down, in some scenarios that would be 10 lines long instead of a simple repo call of the same method. still a map feels a bit overkill for a boolean but I will definitely use it with a bigger case. So thank you for your answear

Comment: @user7673492 in case you found this helpful is any form - you could accept it. Btw, this very much sounds like a `Strategy` pattern also, depending on the boolean or whatever condition you have...